# Can I hide an obsolete widget class from the list of available widgets?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest, android-appwidget

The current version of my app has an app widget, and in the next version I'm replacing it with different widgets. None of them will have the same name or class as the old widget. I don't want the old widget to be available any more.

The problem is that I can't remove the old widget from the manifest, because then all upgrading users will have their widgets deleted from the home screen.

So I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to keep supporting the old widget without showing it in the widgets menu.

Any ideas?